# Vimeo api get folders

Tags: fetch-api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have been trying to get all my folders using Vimeo API. The endpoint /me/projects returns all folders, including subfolders. Is there any way to filter this search so that I can only get Vimeo parent folders or the outermost folders?

I have tried filters like `filter=metadata.connections.ancestor_path.length&filter_metadata.connections.ancestor_path.length=0`, but they don't seem to work.

Thank you!